# javascript pop-up error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've an image column in an `asp:repeater`.

```
<asp:Image ID="telImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../images/telefon.png" />
```

I add `onClick` attribute in `rptList_ItemDataBound`

```
telImage.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript: Redirect('" + telImage.ToolTip + "')");
```

and javascript method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect(url) {
        if (confirm('Do you want to call?')) {
            window.open(url, "ekran", location = 1, status = 1, scrollbars = 1, width = 900, height = 700);               
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click the image, a new window appears but it gives the following error: "HTTP Eror 404.0 - Not Found". How can I solve this?

I only want to run that url address. Is there any basic way? I'm correctly taking the url address.

Comment: What is the `url` parameter of your tooltip?

Comment: telImage.ToolTip is a string like this http://www.google.com I alerted it, it's correct.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment; htpp: // www. google .com (without space)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, url syntax is correct. it also appears

Comment: Try firebug or another debugger.

Comment: @Özkan "htpp: // www. google .com" gives error at firefox are you sure it is working ?

Comment: @Orhan Cinar; that url is only sample. it can be "www.google.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of window.open must be  string.
Try

```
'location = 1, status = 1, scrollbars = 1, width = 900, height = 700'
```